# Adding or Updating multiple entries in Entity Framework with Identity ID and constraint Primary Key on two columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have the following model class:

```
public partial class ORD_Garanzie
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Key]
    public int intestatario { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [Key]
    public string n_polizza { get; set; }
```

........other properties

```
}
```

The method that is adding entries in the DB is as follows:

```
        public ORD_Garanzie[] SaveORD_Garanzie(ORD_Garanzie[] ordGaranzieItems)
    {
        using (TBSContext context = new TBSContext())
        {
            if (ordGaranzieItems.Length != 0 || ordGaranzieItems != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var garanzieItem in ordGaranzieItems)
                    {
                        context.Entry(garanzieItem).State = garanzieItem.ID == 0 ?
                                                            EntityState.Added :
                                                            EntityState.Modified;

                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
                {
                    //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.)
                    throw;
                }

                return ordGaranzieItems;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that if I'm updating the value of one of the properties marked with the [Key] attribute I'm receiving the following error when SaveChanges() is called: `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 
'Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.`

If I am updating any of the other properties that are NOT marked with the KEY attribute in the model class OR adding a new entity completely, I receive no error.

Or if I remove the KEY attributes (and Column attribute) from the model class, the problem goes away.

Any idea how to solve this? Or a better solution to UPDATE or ADD an array of entities when I have this CONSTRAINT that the two properties must be unique. (I also need to be able to change them if need be).

Comment: If you want to change `intestatario` and `n_polizza`, don't make them key properties. There are other ways to enforce uniqueness. If you want them to be key, don't change them. Also you don't need non-key `ID` if they are the key (as far as I understand)

Comment: @grek40 that is true. What I need is to enforce a unique constraint on the combination of those two properties, and them not being keys. I also need the ID to be there as KEY to access records for add/edit/remove since I will use the ID in business logic. (and i don't really want to have composite key from those two properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have your `ID` as key, remove the `Key` annotations from the other columns. To enforce a unique combination of the other columns, use the `Index(name, order, IsUnique=true)` annotation:

```
public partial class ORD_Garanzie
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1)] // optional, not needed for the index
    [Index("IX_SomeIndexName_Unique", 0, IsUnique = true)]
    public int intestatario { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)] // optional, not needed for the index
    [Index("IX_SomeIndexName_Unique", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public string n_polizza { get; set; }
```

Comment: Alright, this is the answer I'm looking for. Found something similar just a few moments ago in another question answered here in SO but because of your first comment.

Comment: Also, do you recommend removing the constraint from the DB, since the DB has the following constraint:   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([intestatario] ASC, [n_polizza] ASC) .   Then I would leave only the Attributes on the model class and make only ID as Key / PrimaryKey.

Comment: @SorinVasiliu basically, the column-order annotated columns will be placed before the not annotated columns, you can skip any number, they will just follow the specified order, not be placed at the specified position.

Comment: Well, now you ask about the necessary changes for an existing database. That's kind of a separate concern to creating the correct database model in the first place